# How to print the text that's inside the a class using BS4?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Html

```
<div class="QRiHXd">
    "Some very secret link" <<< This is the content I want to print out / btw is a link
</div>
```

Code

```
import requests
import urllib
import bs4

url = 'https://www.reddit.com/' # There is actually another link
url_contents = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url_contents, "html.parser")
div = soup.find('div', {'class_': 'QRiHXd'})

content = str(div)
print(content)
```

I need to print the text that's inside the class but when I try to print it it returns: "None" and I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text from a tag you can use the `.text` with the tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<div class="QRiHXd">Some very secret link</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'QRiHXd'})

print(div.text) # Some very secret link
```

Comment: ```File "C:\Users\My PC\Desktop\python 3.9\hw.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(div.text())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'``` I get this error whenever I try to print it out, you know what's the problem?

Comment: i just gave you the reference on how to get the text, either use `.text` or `.get_text()`

Comment: > 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'